from_protobuf in PySpark Decodes false Boolean Values as null
I’m using PySpark’s from_protobuf function to deserialize Protobuf data into a DataFrame. The schema includes a bool field, which is correctly serialized using to_protobuf. However, during deserialization, boolean fields with false values are being decoded as null instead of retaining their false value.
This issue only occurs for fields explicitly set to false—true values deserialize correctly. Has anyone encountered this behavior, and is there a workaround or fix for this?
Environment:
Spark version: 3.5.1
PySpark Protobuf integration: oorg.apache.spark:spark-protobuf_2.12:3.5.1
This is example to re-generate the issue
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.protobuf.functions import from_protobuf, to_protobuf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, BooleanType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Proto3 with PySpark") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-protobuf_2.12:3.5.1") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define Protobuf descriptor and message name
descriptor_path = "example_schema.desc"  # Protobuf descriptor file
target_message = "ExampleSchema"  # Message name in Protobuf schema

# Define PySpark schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("is_active", BooleanType(), True),  # Boolean field
    StructField("status", StringType(), True)       # Additional string field
])

# Sample data with true/false/null for `is_active` and string values for `status`
sample_data = [
    (True, "active"),   # Boolean True with string "active"
    (False, "inactive"),  # Boolean False with string "inactive"
    (None, None)        # Null values for both fields
]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(sample_data, schema=schema)
message_fields=df.columns
df = df.select(struct(*message_fields).alias("event"))

# Serialize to Protobuf
proto_df = df.select(
    to_protobuf(col("event"), target_message, descriptor_path).alias("value")
)

# Deserialize from Protobuf
deserialized_df = proto_df.select(
    from_protobuf(col("value"), target_message, descriptor_path).alias("decoded")
)

# Show deserialized DataFrame
deserialized_df.select("decoded.*").show(truncate=False)

proto file
syntax = "proto3";

message ExampleSchema {
  bool is_active = 1;
  string status = 2;
}

output
+---------+--------+
|is_active|status  |
+---------+--------+
|true     |active  |
|NULL     |inactive|
|NULL     |NULL    |
+---------+--------+

expected output
+---------+--------+
|is_active|status  |
+---------+--------+
|true     |active  |
|false    |inactive|
|NULL     |NULL    |
+---------+--------+

